# В с# невозможно получить-присвоить элемент в массиве Который находится в списке Как в java Верно?

Tags: c#, массивы, list, get, set

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer[]> a = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

        a.add(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        a.add(new Integer[] { 4, 5, 6 });
        a.add(new Integer[] { 7, 8, 9 });

        System.out.println(a.get(1)[1]);
    }
}
```

здесь пример Arraylist
интересует List
**только так что ли?**

```
listofLeftPaths.Add(LLLLarrayofpaths);
        listofLeftPaths.Add(new Vector3[] { Vector3.left });
        randomVectors3Index=random.Next(listofLeftPaths.Count);

        randomVector3 = listofLeftPaths[randomVectors3Index];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопроса не понял. Ориентируюсь на заголовок.

В с# возможно получить/присвоить элемент в массиве.

```cs
var a = List<int[]>();

// заполняем масив
a.Add(someIntArray);

// присваиваем элемент листа вместо старого
a[0] = someIntArray2;

// изменяем элемент массива
a[0][0] = 12;

//получаем элемент листа -- массив:
var arr = a[0];

// получаем элемент массива который лежит в листе:
var elem = a[0][0];
```

Comment: ого работает Спасибо!

Comment: @PODjigateli чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.